# How to display the abbreviated name of the user's timezone (not GMT offset) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I tried something like this:

```
function set_local_time(utcSeconds) {
    var d = new Date(0); // The 0 sets the date to the epoch
    d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds); //update date object with utcSeconds
    return d.toLocaleTimeString() + ', ' + d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toLocaleTimeString('en-us',{timeZoneName:'short'}).split(' ')[2] //time, date timezone 
}
```

Which takes the time and converts it into the user's local time. It works perfectly within the USA (it displays `PDT`, `EDT`, etc.), but outside the USA, it just displays the GMT offset (e.g. `GMT+1`, `GMT+8`, etc.).

Is there a way to display the abbreviated name of the user's timezone internationally? So instead of `GMT+1` for London, it would display `BST` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get this information directly from a `Date` object, but you can get it from the [Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions) interface like this:

```js
let tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
console.log(tz);
```

This will give you the canonical name of the local time zone (e.g. America/New_York). If you want to map the time zone to an abbreviation including daylight savings time (e.g. EST, EDT, PST, EST) your best bet is to use a library like [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external libraries,

```
function getTimezoneShort(timeZone) {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        timeZone: timeZone,
        timeZoneName: 'short'
    }).formatToParts(new Date())
        .find(part => part.type == "timeZoneName")
        .value;
}
```

With Intl.DateTimeFormat you can have a date with abbreviated timezone and then  use formatToParts property on current date to extract the abbreviated timezone.

usage

```
const localTimeZoneShort = getTimezoneShort('America/Toronto');
```

It works with daylight saving times as well.

Comment: This will work for some, as long as the timezone name is available in the `en-US` locale. To get `IST`, the locale has to be supporting, like `en-IN`.

Comment: If I do `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { timeZone: 'Australia/Darwin', timeZoneName: 'long'})` with just the `en` I can get the full name of any timeZone, but when using `short`, I need to use the full locale `en-AU` otherwise I get `GMT+9:30`. This is slightly frustrating, mostly because I can't see a reason for it working one way but not the other?